# javascript - add a value on multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am developing a website with bing map. I've almost done it, but i want to have the pin clustering functionalitty. Then i got this code from the internet:

```
var data = [
        { "latitude": 59.441193, "longitude": 24.729494 },
        { "latitude": 59.432365, "longitude": 24.742992 },
        { "latitude": 59.431602, "longitude": 24.757563 },
        { "latitude": 59.437843, "longitude": 24.765759 },
        { "latitude": 59.439644, "longitude": 24.779041 },
        { "latitude": 59.434776, "longitude": 24.756681 }
    ];
```

I can get the latitude and longitude of every pushpin on my map, but i don't know how to add the latitude and longitude on this array. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
data.push({"latitude": lat, "longitude": lng});
```

Comment: am i right to declare the data array first as var data = [] ?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using the spread operator.

```js
let data = [
        { "latitude": 59.441193, "longitude": 24.729494 },
        { "latitude": 59.432365, "longitude": 24.742992 },
        { "latitude": 59.431602, "longitude": 24.757563 },
        { "latitude": 59.437843, "longitude": 24.765759 },
        { "latitude": 59.439644, "longitude": 24.779041 },
        { "latitude": 59.434776, "longitude": 24.756681 }
    ];

data = [...data, {"latitude": lat, "longitude": lng}]
```

Comment: @SiddiqueThanikad Sorry, that was me. I downvoted because neither the question nor the answer said this was a context where mutating arrays is an issue (like React or VueJS). Outside of that context, adding elements to an array in this way is very unidiomatic. If someone used this without knowing what the difference is, it might lead to unintended consequences.